# Resttemplate JUNIT Exchange method not solving

Tags: java, mockito, resttemplate, junit5

I am trying to write a JUNIT(version 5 ) for a restemplate call.

My actual Implementation is like below .

```
ResponseEntity<OrderDocument> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
URL,
HttpMethod.GET,
new HttpEntity<>(headers),
OrderDocument.class, message.getPayload().toString());
```

My Mock call is

```
when(restTemplate.exchange(anyString() ,
any(HttpMethod.class)   , 
any(HttpEntity.class) ,
any(OrderDocument.class) ,
any(String.class) )
.thenReturn(responseEntity));
```

I am getting compiler error Cannot resolve method 'exchange(java.lang.String, T, T, T, T)'
 I believe my mock call matching with Implementation.Not sure why its not compiling.Please help.

```
 ResponseEntity<T> exchange(String url, HttpMethod method, @Nullable HttpEntity<?> requestEntity, 
 Class<T> responseType, Object... uriVariables) throws RestClientException;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 4th argument of this method is `Class.class`, not `SalesOrderDocument.class`. You need to fix it (to `any(Class.class)`, f.e.).

[Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.lang.String-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-) for `exchange` method.